# Instance Method's and syntax

Tags: objective-c, syntax, methods, nsstring, instance

I'm just wondering if there is a difference in these two types of syntax

Say I have something like this ..

```
NSString *Jam = [[NSString alloc]init];
```

or

```
NSString *Jam;
```

doesn't matter which..

what's the difference between doing the following two lines of code..

```
Jam = [Jam substringToIndex:1];
```

and

```
[Jam substringToIndex:1];
```

and why is it that I find only NSString to be able to pull of something like this..

if I used any other class that I've used so far (I haven't worked with that many), this type of syntax does not work.

Whereas with NSString class I can do

```
NSString *object = [object stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@"];
```

or

```
NSString *object;
object = [object stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@"];
```

but with any other class.. say , NSInteger, if I try the same syntax..

```
NSInteger *number = [number setIntValue:2];
```

I'd get an error telling me void value is not ignored as it ought to be.

Thank's a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

It works for `NSString` because `stringByAppendingFormat` returns a new `NSString` which is created by appending new string to the original one.

`setIntValue` does not return new copy of a class that's why you are getting the error.

Comment: Thank's but what about the first part of the question?